# how to read multiple wav files in python, and convert to numpy arrays to plot

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, wav

I need to read multiple wave files named as chunk1.wav, chunk2.wav... in my project directory and convert them into numpy arrays to plot. I am able to do this for a single wav file, convert it to numpy and plot it using matplotlib, but am not able to do it for an array of wav files.

I searched all over on how to import an array of wav files with the .read() function from the scipy library. I tried using an array of strings, but the read() function does not "understand" a variable as a parameter let alone a string array.
Any advise on how i can achieve this multiple wav read?

```
import pyaudio
import wave
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.silence import split_on_silence
from scipy.io.wavfile import read

no_of_files = 15
file_name = []

for i in range(0, no_of_files):
    file_name.append("chunk{0}.wav".format(i))

a = read(file_name[5]) #test to see if it works for one file
a = np.array(a[1],dtype=float)
plt.plot(a)
plt.show()
```

the error i get:

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/io/wavfile.py", line 168, in _read_riff_chunk
    "understood.".format(repr(str1)))
ValueError: File format ''... not understood.

Comment: Could you show what the value of file_names[5] looks like, I suspect the error is in there but can't be sure

Comment: @SvenH. So when I print(file_name[5]) it gives chunk5.wav which is what I expected

Comment: If that file is not in your current working directory try giving the full path, "C:/.../etc/chunk5.wav"

Comment: @SvenH.  Yes I am sure that the file is in my pwd, I also tried giving the full address but I get the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the scipy internals this is caused by the file signature not being understood, from the error message you get it looks like the file signature is missing (`''`), or there is some other issue reading data from the file:

```
def _read_riff_chunk(fid):
    str1 = fid.read(4)  # File signature
    if str1 == b'RIFF':
        is_big_endian = False
        fmt = '<I'
    elif str1 == b'RIFX':
        is_big_endian = True
        fmt = '>I'
    else:
        # There are also .wav files with "FFIR" or "XFIR" signatures?
        raise ValueError("File format {}... not "
"understood.".format(repr(str1)))
```

**I can't see any similar limitations at a glance using the python `wave` library so potentially try reading in using that and convert the data to a numpy array afterwards**

Comment: so i figured out if i use a = read('name'), where name = "output.wav" is defined as a string, and output.wav is a file in my directory, it works perfectly, but when i used read('file_name[5]') it gives and error, any idea how i can feed in an array string?

Comment: So I now suspect something has happened when these got chunked up, causing them to be missing signatures. I guess doing the above with a `chunk5.wav` instead of `output.wav`should fail

Comment: Yes you’re right. Doing it with “chunk5.wav” does not work. I will look into the missing signatures, these chunks were generated with the pyAudio library where I isolated separate words from a sentence stored in output.wav , and stored each word as chunk.wav. Any idea how I can fix the signatures ? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, not sure, I would just go back and sense check the code that generated the chunks and figure out if it's in the chunking or the saving. I think WAVs are quite structured files so you need to save them in the right way, probably using a library function, chopping up a WAV doesn't look like it gives you multiple wavs